# How to get While loop Data after user clicked on specific Loop Result

Tags: php, html

Right now i'm trying to build an online book store and for selling a book the user has to search by the Book title, ISBN and Author name , **My Question is**  after the search result appears which is generated by a while loop how can i get the books Detail after the user clicked on **Buy** Button and Sale it?

**Here is The SearchResult Code**

```
if($searchID == 2)
    {
            $searchResult = mysqli_query($bookConn , "SELECT * FROM bookt WHERE request = 'Approved' AND bookTitle LIKE '%".$searchtext."%'" ) OR die();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($searchResult))
         {
                ?>


        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div class="container" style="display:block;">
        <hr>


            <!-- /.row -->

            <!-- Page Features -->
            <div class="row text-center">

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://plnami.blob.core.windows.net/media/2015/02/books021715-800x500.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                          <h3>Book Title:<?php  echo $row['bookTitle']; ?></h3>
                            <p>ISBN: <?php  echo $row['ISBN'];          ?></p>
                            <p>Publication Year<?php    echo $row['bookPublicationYear'];  ?> </p>
                            <p>Book Status:<?php echo $row['bookStatus']; ?></p>
                            <p>Book Price: <?php echo  $row['bookPrice']; ?></p>
                            <p>
                                <a href="buyingProcess.php" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now!</a> 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->



        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->

            <?php



        }
    }
```

Comment: Hellow - U could generate a form during the loop of SearchResult assigining the primary key as value of submit button. Then in buyprocess.php u could know which one user clicked. If anyone got a smoother solution ? Otherwise i would like to see ur loop for SearchResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the href of the link put identifying information that you can use on the sell page to look it up using SQL. For example:

```
<a href="buyingProcess.php?isbn=<?php echo row['ISBN'] ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now!</a>
```

Then on the `buyingProcess.php` page, you can run something like

```
    if(isset($_GET['isbn'])){
        $isbn = mysqli_real_escape_string($bookConn , $_GET['isbn']) ;
    }

    $book = mysqli_query($bookConn , "SELECT * FROM bookt WHERE isbn='".$isbn."') OR die();
```

And do with that what you will. `$book` is an object containing all of the information. If you have a cart, you can add it to the cart array. Or you could go straight to the buying process.

**EDIT**

So you want to pass user input as well, which means you'll need a form. The reason your form isn't working is likely because you don't have a submit button. So your form should look like

```
<form action='order.php' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='orderQuantity' id='orderQuantity' size='10' required placeholder='Order Quantity'>
    <button type='submit' name='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then on `order.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string( $bookCon , trim($_POST['orderQuantity'])) ;
}
```

You should also probably put in a JavaScript check on submit that doesn't allow the submit button to be clicked if the input isn't a number.

Comment: This is a good answer, but there remains the danger of a SQL-injection.  Depending on how this code is going to be used, it might become a problem.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) for details.

Comment: Thanks for Your replay @Newspire but what if i want to pass another **parameter** such as **Order Quantity** as an input from the Customer with the <a href="buyingProces............."> is it possible ?!

Comment: @ShkarM For that you'll need to put this all in a form and use the POST method.

Comment: @Newspire it won't allow this is my **code**
<form  action="order.php" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="orderQuantity" id="orderQuantity"  size="10" required Placeholder="Order Quantity">
                        </form>
and i  get the value of the input from another page like that 
$quantity=$_POST['orderQuantity']; 
and its says Undefined index: orderQuantity

Comment: @Newspire appreciate you editing but i already have another button which is Order and if i put another button inside the form it wont make sense!
can i pass the input value with this anchor 
 <a href="order.php?isbn=<?php echo $row['ISBN']  ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Order!</a> </p>